# Excel remove duplicate and get count

Tags: excel, vba

I Have data sheet of 45k data. in below format. What I need to do is get the 1st 3 count from individual number and display.

e.g. if you take 61406142526 you should only count the 1st 3 contents.

```
Number          Content

61406142526 DEW 858

61406142526 DEW 858

61406142526 DEW 858

61406142526 DEW 858

61410140808 DEW 10

61410140808 DEW 9

61410545997 DEW 10
```

The End display should be

```
**DEV 858  = 3**

**DEV 10   = 2**

**DEV  9   = 1**
```

since I'm new to VBA, appreciate anyone can guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use VBA. You can get a unique list by [this way](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/). So when your number is on `A2:A8` and content is on `B2:B8`, first get the unique lists at `C2:C8` and `D2:D8` respectively.

- `C2:C8`: `{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$8), 0)),0)}`
- `D2:D8`: `{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $B$2:$B$8), 0)),0)}`

Now you can get the `n`-th largest number by `large()` formula. So when `F2:F4` is `{1; 2; 3}`, you can get the 1st largest number by `=LARGE($C$2:$C$8,$F2)`. Say this was `G2`, then drag down to `G3:G4` and you got the 2nd and 3rd largest numbers now.

Now you can search those numbers at `C2:C8` and retrieve its corresponding content at `D2:D8`. Generally one can use `index() & match()` formula for this. So type `=INDEX($D$2:$D$8, MATCH($G2,$C$2:$C$8,0))` at `H2` and drag down to `H3:H4`. Finished. Sample file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqmh85ckyda1gdf/43134590.xlsx?dl=0).

[image]